# write a program that get data of 100 students and display merit list

Tags: c++, object

Recently I have come across a peculiar question in c++:

> create a class named student which contains the following members: roll,name & course.
>   Write a program to read the information of n students and then display
>   the information of the students *within an input roll no range*. Use
>   constructors & member functions.

How is it possible to display info within a an input roll_no range while there is no database in use ? It sounds peculiar.

I have a simple solution as given below:
But,I want a better algorithm which is more economic in terms of memory and processor speed.

```
 #include<iostream.h>
     #include<conio.h>
     class student
     {
       int roll;
       char name[100];
       char course[100];
       public:void getData();
          void disp(int r1,int r2)
          {
            if(roll>=r1 && roll<=r2)
            cout<<"\nroll_no:"<<roll<<"\tname:"<<name<<"\tcourse:"<<course;
          }
     };
     void student::getData()
     {
        cout<<"\nEnter roll_no,name and course\n";
        cin>>roll>>name>>course;
     }
     void main()
     {
       student s[100];
       int n,r1,r2;
       clrscr();
       cout<<"\nEnter no of students\n";
       cin>>n;
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        s[i].getData();
       cout<<"\nEnter the range\n";
       cin>>r1>>r2;
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        s[j].disp(r1,r2);
       getch();
     }
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  Using search criteria doesn't require a database.

Comment: As I understand it, you're required to write a program that stores the data in memory, therefore everything is supposed to happen during the run of the program. Nothing here suggests any kind of persistance.

Comment: i think i should make use of constructor to automatically increment roll_no. user has to input a range of numbers.then check those numbers whether they fall in the range.but its unnecessary.could anyone provide me with a clever idea? @Chad

Comment: you are right @SirDarius. i think these types of questions in c++ is unnecessary unless its a database project.right?

Comment: I don't think you will get malus points for using a database in your program though, but you're going to put much more work into it than required for an introductory exercise to C++ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to your exercise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Student{
    Student(unsigned int r) : roll(r), name(), course() {}
    unsigned int roll;
    string name;
    string course;
};

int main(){
    vector<Student> students;
    //populate the vector with meaningful data, here only roll is written
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        students.push_back(Student(i));

    unsigned int min = 45;
    unsigned int max = 85;
    auto operation = [=](const Student& e){if( (e.roll >= min) and (e.roll <= max) ) cout << e.roll << endl;};
    for_each(students.begin(), students.end(), operation);
}
```

which you can try [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=78040489a0444e3827fb55b40cc20f58-37e310707bc41fe992acad9d9b03bc56).

Of course everything is dummy here, the purpose of this code is to show you how you are working with collections of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instructor, then ask the instructor if the roll_no is incremented automatically or if it is part of the User input.  Clarification of requirements is job 1.

You would need a container, such as a vector or a map to hold all the objects.

- Input an object and store into container.
- Repeat until User says no more input.
- If using a vector, sort by roll_no.
- Prompt user for start range and end range for printing.
- Search the container for the first roll_no that is greater than or
  equal to the start range.
- Print from that location in the container until the roll_no is
  greater than or equal to the end range.

Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.